# Java swing: Remanence when removing a heavyweight jogl component to add a lightweight component at the same place

Tags: java, swing, jogl

In my swing application, when I remove a *jogl* **GLCanvas** from my main component to add a **jPanel** at the same place, there are some display glitches:
During the time when the old component has been removed and before the new one has been added, remanent images of all the popup menus that have been displayed before on top of the **GLCanvas** are visible on the background of the main component.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

When adding/removing components from a visible GUI the code should look like:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Also, **the code should execute on the Event Dispatch Thread**. If code is executed from within a listener then it is on the EDT. If the code is executed outside of a listener then you probably need to use a SwingWorker or SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: I think revalidate itself organizes the necessary repaint, so you don't have to call this too. The more important part is the EDT, though.

Comment: There are times when repaint is absolutely essentially, especially when removing components, so revalidate is many times not enough.

Comment: Sorry I have not been specific enough in my question... I know about the need to do this in the EDT... It is just not enough when mixing heavyweight jogl components with lightweight swing components. I have edited my question to be more specific.